# How to safely write to GUI from different thread in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, xamarin

I've downloaded a trial version of Xamarin and am currently playing around with it (in Visual Studio 2010).

One of the tests that I wanted to do was to see how to make an Activity where I update a control on the GUI via a BackgroundWorker thread - Specifically, I was interested to see how different the Mono syntax would be compared to a regular Windows Forms (C#) syntax.

To test this out, I created an Android Application (again, in VS2010) targeting API Level 17 (Android 4.2). The general functionality of the app will change the text value of an EditText control from within a _DoWork() BackgroundWorker event handler.

Here's the code..

```
//Xamarin.Android app
[Activity(Label = "Cross-thread Test", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    EditText labelDisplay;
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
    int counter = 0;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        this.bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);

        Button buttonStart = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonStart);
        buttonStart.Click += new EventHandler(buttonStart_Click);

        Button buttonStop = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonStop);
        buttonStop.Click += new EventHandler(buttonStop_Click);

        labelDisplay = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.labelDisplay);
        labelDisplay.Text = "Click Start";
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (this.bgWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => labelDisplay.Text = "Click Start");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;

                            // This causes GREF to increase to 2001
                RunOnUiThread(() => labelDisplay.Text = counter.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.bgWorker != null && !this.bgWorker.IsBusy)
            this.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.bgWorker != null && this.bgWorker.IsBusy)
            this.bgWorker.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

For whatever it's worth, I'm attempting to use the `RunOnUiThread()` in the similar way that I use `Invoke()` in a regular `Windows Forms` like this...

```
//Regular Windows Forms app
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.bgWorker.CancellationPending)
            break;
        else
        {
            counter++;
            //This isn't possible in a Xamarin.Android app, which is why I'm using RunOnUiThread() instead
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => { this.labelDisplay.Text = counter.ToString(); })); 
        }
    }
}
```

The Xamarin.Android application will crash where the Debug output reveals the following error (I've only included notable info)...

```
09-28 18:09:39.231 D/dalvikvm(  731): GREF has increased to 1701
09-28 18:09:39.461 D/dalvikvm(  731): GREF has increased to 1801
09-28 18:09:40.192 D/dalvikvm(  731): GREF has increased to 1901
09-28 18:09:40.271 D/dalvikvm(  731): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 7% free 6175K/6599K, paused 3ms+5ms
09-28 18:09:40.531 D/dalvikvm(  731): GREF has increased to 2001
09-28 18:09:40.531 W/dalvikvm(  731): JNI global reference table (0x475fd0) dump:
09-28 18:09:40.531 W/dalvikvm(  731):   Last 10 entries (of 2001):
09-28 18:09:40.531 W/dalvikvm(  731):      2000: 0x40fa4e90 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
09-28 18:09:40.541 W/dalvikvm(  731):      1999: 0x40fb2e78 mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor
.
.
.
09-28 18:09:40.581 E/dalvikvm(  731): Excessive JNI global references (2001) //OOPS!
09-28 18:09:40.581 E/dalvikvm(  731): VM aborting
09-28 18:09:40.581 E/mono-rt (  731): Stacktrace:
09-28 18:09:40.581 E/mono-rt (  731): 
09-28 18:09:40.592 E/mono-rt (  731):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
09-28 18:09:40.592 E/mono-rt (  731):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.wrapper_native_0x408027e9 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>
09-28 18:09:40.592 E/mono-rt (  731):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.NewGlobalRef (intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.2-branch/bdc709d1/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:389
```

I read [Xamarin's Troubleshooting page](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting) that states

> Dalvik's JNI layer only supports a limited number of JNI object
>   references to be valid at any given point in time. When this limit is
>   exceeded, things break.
>
> The GREF (global reference) limit is 2000 references in the emulator,
>   and ~52000 references on hardware.
>
> You know you're starting to create too many GREFs when you see
>   messages such as this in the Android Debug Log:

You'll notice in the error log that my code increased the GREF to 2001.

Based on the troubleshooting notes above, I'm assuming that the `RunOnUiThread()` is creating a JNI object for each iteration of the while loop. If this is the case, why is this occurring and what should I do to write to the GUI from a different thread safely?

Answer (score 2):

`RunOnUiThread` *queues* the work.

The technique for updating the UI is OK, it's just that with no pause in the loop, that queue hits 2000 items almost instantaneously.

I bet it would be fine with a short `Thread.Sleep()` in there...

Comment: I originally had a call to Sleep(1000) in my code, but the problem persists. Granted the GREF increases much slower, but eventually hits the 2000 ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

try to write your UI update in this

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     // code to execute
});
```

Comment: Question is about `Xamarin.Android` not `Xamarin.Form`!